# Read access token that will be validated inside a JWT passport in nestjs

Tags: jwt, nestjs, user-agent

I am building a nestjs back-end api server, and I'm using JWT to authenticate and validate user requests through passport strategies.
My question: I want to read the access token inside the validate function of JWT strategy.
Below: an example of my code
Note: my goal is to decode the access token and get the user agent I use to generate the token for an extra validation layer (to make sure the request is coming from the same device). If you have a better way, I would be happy to know it :)

```
    import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';


@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWTSecret,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
   
    //I want to read the access token that would be validated here 
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username , useragent: payload.useragent};
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sessions` for this?

Comment: If you really need the `accesstoken` you can access it through the `request` object of `express`

Comment: And the `payload` argument is your decode access token. You can work with this. https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt

Comment: I can't use sessions because my requirements is seasonless service.

Comment: Payload argument doesn't contain the user agent object although i used it to generate the token

Comment: I know I can get the accesstoken through req object but that won't be possible inside the passport

Answer (score 0):

You can forward the request to the `validate` method.

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: 'SECRET'
            passReqToCallback: true, // This is the key parameter
        })
    }

    // First parameter is the Request object
    async validate(req: Request, payload: DecryptedPayload) {
        const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(req)
        if (!token) throw new UnauthorizedException()

        // Do whatever you need to do with the encrypted access token

        return payload
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It turn out that I was not using the user agent in payload.
So to answer my own question and like @W.S said, you can use the payload to find all of the payload components.